# NoMethodError in Rails: Passing variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass in the variable "post" to a partial. The partial is being used on both my show#view & I'm also rendering a collection using it. Here's what it looks like (notice the "@"):

```
##Show#View
<%= render 'my_partial/my_view', post: @post %>
##Collection ## (I'm not using the "@" symbol)
<%= render 'my_partial/my_view', post: post %>


#Mypartial

<% if @post.something? %>
   ## do this
<% else %>
   ## do that
<% end %>
```

And then I get the beautiful `NoMethodError undefined method`something?' for nil:NilClass` page when using it in my collection. I know why I'm getting it, I'm just wondering what's the DRY way(s) of getting this to work? Should I just create another partial?

Thank you

---

Gave my solution below.. Though, it's probably not the best way...

Comment: Your partial must reference `post`, which is the "local" you're defining, not `@post`, which is an instance variable and undefined in the case of a collection.

Comment: Hey @meagar I just read some of you're comments & I totally get it now but I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error. I went ahead & accepted the answer you said was correect but could you shed some light as to y I might be getting this error still? Thanks

Comment: @meagar nvm, I think I know what it is.. I think it's because I'm using a permalink as the id.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you referencing `@post` in your partial? You should use `post` instead, that is the entire point of what you are doing (passing variables to a partial as local variables).

Comment: What? Why does it matter?

Comment: What do you think the `post: @post` and `post: post` are doing? They are telling your partial what the `post` variable refers to. So why are you referencing `@post` in your partial instead of `post`, when `@post` is not defined in the collection context? The whole point of what you are doing is to define a local variable (`post`) so that in both the singular & collection cases the partial can render given the appropriate variable.

Comment: I understand exactly what you are doing. You just don't understand what I'm telling you. I have made it as clear as I possibly could. Good luck.

Comment: @Jon This answer is correct; use `post` in your partial, not `@post`. This is how locals work, when passed to a partial, you're telling it what variables to define, and what their value is. The `@post` is the *value*, the `post` is the *name of the variable*. Your partial needs to use `post`.

Comment: I know you're right. This is what I was initially doing & after rereading the rails docs  to confirm it, I think the problem is since I'm using a permalink as my id, it's passing my permalink instead of my actual id. Maybe this will help someone else with this problem, but thank you :) (I deleted my other replies so this reply will be more noticeable)

Answer (score -1):

You must change the rendering to:

```
<%= render 'my_partial/my_view', locals: { post: @post } %>
```

Take a look in the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Search for "3.4.4 Passing Local Variables" and you will find more information about this whole stuff.

And for fixing your collection problem also check out the rails guide and search for: "3.4.5 Rendering Collections".

Comment: This hasn't been true for quite a while. You don't need to explicitly use `locals: { ... }` anymore, Rails will handle `render "partial", variable: @variable` just fine, treating `variable: @variable` as the `locals` option.

Comment: @meagar I just copy that from the official rails guide :). You can take a look at the guide. So it is not false, but maybe your style is newer.